# GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos credentails) in web browser using AWS Network Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kerberos, amazon-elb, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have created an Cloudera cluster on a AWS architecture using Ec2.
There a two Yarn Resource Manager, and when I access the Resource Manager Web UI link directly by one of the two nodes it works.
There is a Network Load Balancer with a TCP listener that forwards to a target group than include the two Resource Manager.
When I try to access the Load balancer, via browser (Chrome or Firefox), sometimes there is the error:

HTTP ERROR 403
GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos credentails)

In other cases it works well.
Any solutions?

Thanks